# Simple flask service do not respond outside a docker container

Tags: docker, flask

Hi and thanks in advance, I'm new to docker, I'm stuck on a simple docker example exposing a flask service outside a container.

I have a folder called `rest_example` and inside a dockerfile and a .py file.
This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
LABEL maintainer="Lorem Ipsum"
RUN apt-get update  &&  \
    apt-get install -y python  && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip  && \
    pip install Flask  && \
    apt-get install -y curl  && \
    mkdir files
COPY flask_example.py /files
ENV FLASK_APP /files/flask_example.py
EXPOSE 5000
CMD flask run
```

This is flask_example.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

I'm creating image like this: 
docker run rest_example -t -p 5000:5000 --name=rest_example --rm

When I hit `curl localhost:5000/hello` inside the container this is the response:
`Hello World!`, is means that flask is up inside the container BUT, in my local browser there are not response for that url.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#a-minimal-application), you'll find:

> Externally Visible Server
>
> If you run the server you will notice that
>   the server is only accessible from your own computer, not from any
>   other in the network. This is the default because in debugging mode a
>   user of the application can execute arbitrary Python code on your
>   computer.
>
> If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network,
>   you can make the server publicly available simply by adding
>   --host=0.0.0.0 to the command line:
>
> flask run --host=0.0.0.0
>
> This tells your operating system to listen on
>   all public IPs.

You did publish port 5000 when starting your container, but did not instruct Flask to actually listen on 'external' interface.

You did start the container properly for linking the 'external' of the container to your local machine, but there is nothing listenting there.

Try your dockerfile like this, adding the parameter mentioned in the documentation shown above:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
LABEL maintainer="Lorem Ipsum"
RUN apt-get update  &&  \
    apt-get install -y python  && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip  && \
    pip install Flask  && \
    apt-get install -y curl  && \
    mkdir files
COPY flask_example.py /files
ENV FLASK_APP /files/flask_example.py
EXPOSE 5000
CMD flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, bgse, that work's and I understood the explain.

Answer (score 1):

A better option will be to disable the debugger and force the flask app to listen on all interfaces directly from your code without modifying the Dockerfile.

Here's a nice working snippet:

```
from flask import Flask

# init the app
app = Flask(__name__)

# sample route
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name == '__main__':

    # running the server
    app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0')
```